# Trying to hide sheets based on cell value for a range of cells to a range of sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, cell, show-hide

I have a workbook that is getting very packed when it comes to the worksheets. I do not use all of them all the time, and so I want to hide unused ones at the time based on what i'm working on.

I have a main Index that has a column that has G2:G30 for the range of values to indicate if the sheet will be shown.
I have a range of sheets that have been numbered for referencing below that range from 1,2,3,..... to 26.
I have a Simple VBA solution that will show the single G2 of "Y" to show or to hide otherwise. I have zero clue about how this will look to iterate through these 2 ranges to match things up. They are incremental.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If [G2] = "Y" Then
        Sheets("1").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("1").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I really need this to iterate through the range to indicate to the sheets in the worksheet.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? If G3="Y" then sheets("2") is visible etc?

Comment: G is your yes/no, but the sheet names... are those adjacent in F or what?  Your change event can reference the specific target intersect of columns("G") but the sheet reference could be `sheets(cells(activecell.row,activecell.column-1).value).visible = `.  Similarly, if row 2 = sheet 1, then you can have `sheets(activecell.row-1).visible = `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest a little change to your request. If you add the sheet name in cells H2:H30, then you can do something like this:

```
Dim SheetRef As Range
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
For Each SheetRef In Range("G2:G30")
    Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetRef.Offset(0, 1).Value)
    TargetSheet.Visible = (UCase(SheetRef.Value) = "Y")
Next
```

This will read the name of the sheet from the cell to the right of G2, G3 etc and use that to control the visibility.
If you don't do that, you will have to find another way of knowing what toggle refers to what sheet.

Comment: I tried this, but does not seem to work for me and I don't know why. Does it hide anything not Y?

Gives me a compile error:  Invalid outside procedure for the For Each SheetRef line.

Comment: Looks like this would be a standalone subroutine rather than a change event and could loop through all cells in the range and assess against the specific sheet name listed.  Could work as a button, which bases visibility on a True/False scenario for the value being "Y"

Comment: @Cyril - I agree. Putting this in the original Worksheet_Change would be risky

Comment: @Sam may want to add `ucase()` around your sheetref.value to ensure 'y' and "Y" are treated similar.

Comment: Fuanctioning.....
This took some playing around with the offset. Turns out needed to add a row at the end, and 1,1 for my values but working as needed and added the case in just for good measure.
THANK YOU ALL.

Comment: @PantheonEngineeringDesigns make sure to accept an answer (check box to the left of the post).

Answer (score 0):

You could try similar to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(30, 7))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
        Case "Y"
            Sheets(Target.Row).Visible = True
        Case "N"
            Sheets(Target.Row).Visible = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

This will work purely based on the row of your target

[image]

---

If you have a name of a sheet in an adjacent cell, you could try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(30, 7))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
        Case "Y"
            Sheets(Cells(Target.Row,Target.Column-1).Value).Visible = True
        Case "N"
            Sheets(Cells(Target.Row,Target.Column-1).Value).Visible = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Tested with 4 sheets, Sheet1 (aka sheets(1)) through sheet4 (aka sheets(4)).